# How to open only browser in notification android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-browser

I want to open only a browser on click of a notification.
I am using this code but it always open both (app and browser)

```
if (!url.startsWith(GLOBAL.DOMAIN_NAME) ) {       
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, as it's the app that opens the browser.

Comment: Thanks for edited my question

Answer (score 0):

All you need is setting a flag to the intent.

Add this

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Like this :
`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));                
                startActivity(i);`

Comment: @Nugraha: Yes. Try it.

Comment: still not happen anything :(